# Possible to renew table counter?

Tags: environment-variables

Can I renew the table counter to use my own counter similarly to renewing, for instance, the `\tablename`? What is the keyword or where could I look for it?

This will be used within a `newenvironment` based on `tabu` (in order to have a separate counter from the table environment).

This is for the environment created in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183475/new-environment-type-without-automatic-numbering) question. When we click in a hyperlink in the PDF, we are always sent to the first Interface or last Table in the document. I believe the reason may be that `hyperref` relies on the table counter to work properly; if we comment out the counter decrease, `\addtocounter{table}{-1}`, in the environment definition then: hyperlinks work well, but table numbering is incorrect.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable, tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\ListOfInterfacesName}{List of Interfaces}
\newcommand{\InterfaceName}{Interface}

% Define list of interfaces command
\makeatletter%
  \newcommand{\listofinterfaces}{%
    \section*{\ListOfInterfacesName}%
    \@starttoc{int}  % New toc with extension *.int%
    \clearpage%
  }%
\makeatother%

% Usage: {}{<label>}{<ifNum>}{<caption>}
\newenvironment{ryetable}[4]{%
  \renewcommand{\tablename}{\InterfaceName} % Safe to renew table because it is inside a group
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{#3} % Explicitly set table number to given argument (safe because redifinition also occurs inside a group)
  \addtocounter{table}{-1} % Reduce counter number since using table increases it automatically
  \addcontentsline{int}{subsection}{\protect{\numberline{#3}{#4}}} % Define entry subsection akin to normal tables
  \gdef\tmpheaders{#1} % Not currently used
  \gdef\tmplabel{\label{#2}} % Save label for later use
  \gdef\tmpifnum{#3} % Save interface number
  \gdef\tmpcaption{\caption[]{#4}} % Save caption for later use ---> drop the entry to the table list
  \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {@{} X[1,l] X[1,l] X[1,l] >{\raggedright}X[1,l] @{}}
    \\\toprule\rowfont\bfseries
    Header1 & Header2 & Header3 & Description \\
    \midrule
  \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{\small\textit{(continued)}}\\
    \toprule\rowfont\bfseries
    Header1 & Header2 & Header3 & Description \\
    \midrule
  \endhead
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}r@{}}{\small\textit{(continues)}}\\
  \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \tmpcaption
    \tmplabel
  \endlastfoot
}{%
  \end{longtabu}
}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\listofinterfaces %TODO
\section{MySection}
For a nifty new environment check Interface~\ref{if:myinterface}.
\begin{ryetable}{}{if:myinterface}{31}{This is my pretty interface.}
a & b & c & d\\
e & f & g & h\\
i & j & k & l\\
m & n & o & p\\
q & r & s & t\\
u & v & w & x\\
y & z & -- & --\\
\end{ryetable}

% Some other table to show on list
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c}
    a&b\\
    c&d\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption of tabular table.}
  \label{tab:somelabel}
\end{table}

\newpage
\begin{ryetable}{}{if:myif2}{35}{This is the other interface.}
a & b & c & d\\
e & f & g & h\\
i & j & k & l\\
m & n & o & p\\
q & r & s & t\\
u & v & w & x\\
y & z & -- & --\\
\end{ryetable}
Go to Interface~\ref{if:myif2}. % Incorrectly links to first environment
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(long)tabu just inherits its counter usage from `longtable` (I'd just use the latter personally) but the issue is the same.

I've started to implement that as an option in a possible future version  but in V4 it isn't directly available.

For simple use you can just locally reset the `{table}` counter to be the value of your custom counter and set `\thetable` the main issue is that `longtable` hardwires the list of tables in its caption handling so you will need to locally redefine

```
\makeatletter
\def\LT@c@ption#1[#2]#3{%
  \LT@makecaption#1\fnum@table{#3}%
  \def\@tempa{#2}%
  \ifx\@tempa\@empty\else
     {\let\\\space
     \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\protect\numberline{\thetable}{#2}}}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

so it doesn't use `\fnum@table` (it could use `My zzz \thezzz` instead if you are using `zzz` counter) and similarly change `lot` and `table` to use whatever list of zzz file you have set up.)

Comment: Longtable skips/increases counter when no caption is used in the previous longtable... I could not renew the counter using \setcounter. Anyway out?

Comment: @Khaaba I'm not sure I understand the issue, you can always go `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` to undo longtable's increment if it is a problem.

Comment: If possible, longtable counter may not increment if \caption is not in use in the longtable environment. At the moment, the counter increments even if \caption is not used.